# Removing quotes from python variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code snippet

```
import requests, json
key = "1kjhnuig2"
def api_call():
  r = requests.post('https://myFancyUrl',headers={'Authorization': 'ApiKey "' + (key) + '"'})
...
```

When I run this function the Authorization header ends up looking like this:

```
'Authorization': 'ApiKey "1kjhnuig2"'
```

But the receiving system will not accept this call because the API key has quotes around it.  How can I remove the quotes and have the following output?

```
'Authorization': 'ApiKey 1kjhnuig2'
```

I've tried using replace, strip, eval, etc and can't seem to get my desired outcome.

Comment: You explicitly add quotes when creating the header: `'ApiKey "' + (key) + '"'`. Simply remove them.

Comment: What is your desired outcome ?

Comment: Or use f -string `'Authorization': f'ApiKey {key}'`

Comment: This one worked as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this like

```
headers={'Authorization': '"','ApiKey' ,+ (key)  '"'}
```

the result will be 'Authorization': "ApiKey 1kjhnuig2"

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. There's a lot of unnecessary syntax.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).